# Add entries to an object

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

A php script is computing me the following array:

```
$test = Array();
$test['a'] = Array();
$test['a']['a1'] = 'a1';
$test['a']['a2'] = 'a2';
$test['b'] = Array();
$test['b']['b1'] = 'b1';
$test['b']['b2'] = 'b2';
```

I'm converting this array into JSON using:

```
echo json_encode($test);
```

I'm retrieving this JSON using an Ajax call, and I'm turning this it into a JavaScript array using:

```
test = JSON.parse(data);
```

My question is: How can I add entries to this array in JavaScript?
I tried:

```
test['c'] = [];
test['c']['c1'] = 'c1';
test['c']['c2'] = 'c2';
```

But then in the console `test['c']` is empty (`Array[0]`).

Comment: Show the JSON too, then we do not have to do json_encoding in our heads

Comment: `test['c'] = []; test['c'].push('c1')';test['c'].push('c2')';` If you set `test['c']` as array, use `.push` to add data, set property `c1, c2` won't have effect on its `length`, and it will still be an empty array. If you want `c1, c2` as key, set `test['c']` as `object`, use `test['c'] = {};`

Comment: @fuyushimoya - there is nothing wrong with his code or the way he do it -> http://jsfiddle.net/EJZ48/710/ **if** of course `test` actually _is_ an object in the first place.

Comment: @fuyushimoya - if `test = JSON.parse(data)` is performed successfully then `test` is a valid object you can append new attributes with arrays to, just the way OP does.

Comment: PS: @fuyushimoya: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Comment: @davidkonrad I know you can, and it will show `Array[0]` when you console.log it, just as OP saw, the first part of my comment seems to be misleading. Should just state that the OP just set `test['c']` as array and explain why it result in `Array[0]`.

Comment: @mplungjan I knew, that, but I forget that the answer I commented use 'c1' => 'c1' or c1 => 'c1', thx for the notice anyway.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After this point:

```
test = JSON.parse(data);
```

you're not dealing with JSON anymore; `test` is an **object**.

> ...and I'm turning this it into a JavaScript array using...

You're not turning it into a JavaScript *array*, you're turning it into a JavaScript *object*. JavaScript's nearest equivalent to PHP's "associative array" is an object, not an array.

To add properties to objects, you just assign to them. In your case, you're trying to create a property named `c` that's an object with additional properties. Since we use objects, not arrays, for that in JavaScript, you'd create `c` using `{}` rather than `[]`. E.g.:

```
test['c'] = {};
test['c']['c1'] = 'c1';
test['c']['c2'] = 'c2';
```

or more concisely:

```
test.c = {};
test.c.c1 = 'c1';
test.c.c2 = 'c2';
```

or even *more* concisely:

```
test.c = {
    c1: 'c1',
    c2: 'c2'
};
```

---

What you were doing *would* work, because normal JavaScript arrays [are really objects](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2011/01/myth-of-arrays.html) and so you can add arbitrary, non-element properties to them as well as using them in the more "normal" way. But in the normal case, you'd use non-array objects instead.

> But then in the console test['c'] is empty (Array[0])

That's because the console is showing you the array-like aspects of the object and ignoring the non-array aspects. But `test['c']` **did** have `c1` and `c2` properties, the console just didn't show them to you. Nevertheless, only use non-index property names with arrays if you have a specific reason for doing so. Otherwise, again, use non-array objects.

Answer (score -1):

In javascript you can't have named indexes.

From http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_arrays.asp

> Many programming languages support arrays with named indexes. Arrays
>   with named indexes are called associative arrays (or hashes).
>   JavaScript does not support arrays with named indexes. In JavaScript,
>   arrays always use numbered indexes.   If you use a named index,
>   JavaScript will redefine the array to a standard object. After that,
>   all array methods and properties will produce incorrect results.

Comment: Yes you can. You shouldn't but you can: http://andrewdupont.net/2006/05/18/javascript-associative-arrays-considered-harmful/

Comment: Yet another example of why you really shouldn't be using w3schools. Consider just about any other reference; [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript) is typically (not universally, but typiclly) of a high standard.